# Unable to capture XML response value to a property mediator

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-esb

I have created a api using wso2 integration studio and below is the xml response sent to the post api.The api accept xml response.

```
<ns3:result xmlns:response="http://inforwisse.co.ts/broker/response" xmlns:ns3="http://inforwis

e.co.tz/broker/" xmlns:request="http://inforwisse.co.ts/broker/request">

    <ns3:resultType>Completed</ns3:resultType>

    <ns3:resultCode>0</ns3:resultCode>

    <ns3:resultDesc>Success</ns3:resultDesc>

    <ns3:originatorConversationID>025d7efd-58bc-b06b-2a9b91cdd3d1</ns3:originatorConversationID>

    <ns3:conversationID>025d7efd-58bc-b06b-2a9b91cdd3d1</ns3:conversationID>

    <ns3:mpesaReceipt>5BL716QNJLM</ns3:mpesaReceipt>

    <ns3:transactionID>125189978</ns3:transactionID>

    <ns3:resultParameters>

        <ns3:parameter>

            <ns3:key>Amount</ns3:key>

            <ns3:value>Tsh15,000</ns3:value>

        </ns3:parameter>

        <ns3:parameter>

            <ns3:key>Transaction Datetime</ns3:key>

            <ns3:value>15/03/2018 19:43:15</ns3:value>

        </ns3:parameter>

        <ns3:parameter>

            <ns3:key>Working Account Available Funds</ns3:key>

            <ns3:value>0.00</ns3:value>

        </ns3:parameter>

        <ns3:parameter>

            <ns3:key>Utility Account Available Funds </ns3:key>

            <ns3:value>0.00</ns3:value>

        </ns3:parameter>

        <ns3:parameter>

            <ns3:key>Charges Paid Account Available Funds </ns3:key>

            <ns3:value>0.00</ns3:value>

        </ns3:parameter>

    </ns3:resultParameters>

</ns3:result>
```

I tried to store the value of the resultType as below

```
 <property expression="//ns3:resultType/text()" name="resultType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

I got the below error when I tried to print the resultType using a log mediator

```
[2023-09-28 17:00:12,174]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:mpesa-agent-v1-api:v1.0.0} To: /mpesa-agent/1.0.0/cashin/callback, MessageID: urn:uuid:82c9e0d0-a1ad-425f-b870-414d43cd767d, correlation_id: 82c9e0d0-a1ad-425f-b870-414d43cd767d, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Evaluation of the XPath expression //ns3:resultType/text() resulted in an error, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns3:result xmlns:ns3="http://inforwise.co.tz/broker/" xmlns:request="http://inforwise.co.tz/broker/request" xmlns:response="http://inforwise.co.tz/broker/response">
```

The property isnt saving the resultType value

Comment: Give more details of what you are doing.    Are you trying to parse the response?  Or maybe add the node property to the response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your `ns3` namespace in `property mediator` like below:

```
 <property name="resultType" expression="//ns3:resultType/text()" xmlns:ns3="http://inforwise.co.tz/broker/" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```